# Querying the disk drive of device manager on a remote computer

Tags: c#, sql, powershell

I need to find out the names of disk drives from the device manager on a remote computer using Powershell script. Does anyone know how to ? Being very specific , till now I have been able to get the physical drives and partitions , but not the required. Please find attached a screenshot of exactly what i need.

Here's the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2AMH.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using wmi:

```
 gwmi Win32_DiskDrive -ComputerName remotecomputername | select model
```

The user must have local administrator credentials of remote computer and remote computer firewall must not block wmi query.

Comment: Thank you so much !!! it worked.. but the names of certain drives doesnt match exactly

Comment: @user2042493 try to do `select model,caption` to see who is the better match.

Comment: @user2042493 I Have tried here with some remote computer and all matches.. maybe some name in 'device manager' is taken from other wmi object.

Comment: Also the above mentioned query does not return me the names of disk drives that are connected to a SAN on the remote server , any idea how to figure that out ?

Comment: @user2042493 try read here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/a5d6a502-f583-41e4-aee5-da41e378f8d2/

Comment: I couldn't find anything helpful there. Still no positive results